# GUI FileViewer program file loading problems

Tags: java, user-interface, java1.4

I am currently working on a java 1.4.2 GUI file reading/saving/encrypting program. Since it is over 500 lines, I will not post the whole thing here...I will post the part I am having a problem with. The problem I am having is with the encryption feature, where the box pops up to enter the name of the file you want to encrypt, however no matter what you enter, you get a FileNotFound exception before you are even given the chance to enter a file name. The open and save features work fine, its just the encryption part.

Here it is:

```
public void encrypt() throws IOException
{

        openWin = new JFrame("Encrypt File");

        Container openFile = openWin.getContentPane();


        JLabel L1;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton encryptButton;

        L1 = new JLabel ("Choose File to Encrypt: ");

        panel.add(L1);
        output = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(output);

        encryptButton = new JButton("Encrypt File");
        encryptButton.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(encryptButton);

        openFile.add(panel);

        openWin.setBounds(50,100,400,150);
        openWin.setVisible(true);


    //Get the current content pane
    contentPane = this.getContentPane();

    //refresh the content pane
    if(mainPanel !=null)
        contentPane.remove(mainPanel);

    //Create a new mainPanel
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
        //We need a buffered reader to read the file
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    //Temp will hold heach line read in, text will be the final string
    String temp="";
    String text="";


    //read the first line
    temp = in.readLine();

    int length = temp.length();

    String encrypted = in.readLine();

    int index = temp.length() - 1;

    //loop until the file has ended
    while(index >= 0)
    {

        encrypted = encrypted + temp.charAt(index);

        index--;

        //read another line
        temp = in.readLine();
    }

    //create the text area.
    //send it (String data, height, width)

    page = new JTextArea(text,30,50);
    //Set line wrap to true, other wise it would just be one looooong line
    page.setLineWrap(true);

    //Here is where we create our scroll pane.
    scrollpane = new JScrollPane(page);


    //the page is connected to the scrollpane, the scrollpane gets connected to the mainPanel
    mainPanel.add(scrollpane);

    //The mainPanel is connected to the contentPane
    contentPane.add(mainPanel);

    //refresh the JFrame!
    validate();

}
```

Any ideas what I did wrong? This is my first experience using GUI programming..

Comment: If you get that exception is because the file does not exist, at least not the one in the fileName variable. I'm pretty sure you're getting that wrong somewhere. Post the code where you are setting fileName.

Comment: Could you post the StackTrace of the Exception?

Comment: its simply "java.io.FileNotFoundException:"

Comment: Can you print out the absolute name of the file? Something like: System.out.println(new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath());

Comment: It doesn't ever reach reading a file...it gives the exception right when I click on encrypt from the drop down menu. Before the box even appears that lets you enter a file name.

Comment: Is it possible that the fileName variable is still empty at the time you call new FileReader(fileName)? I would still recommend to add the System.out before calling new FileReader().

Answer (score 1):

Which value has the 'fileName' variable? Perhaps you should use a JFileChooser.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

Comment: fileName is "String fileName = ""; " under the public class fileViewer

Answer (score 1):

Do you use double slashes when giving java the file's path?
For example, instead of

```
D:\Java\EncryptFile.txt
```

it should be

```
D:\\Java\\EncryptFile.txt
```

because the backslash is the escape character in Java.

Comment: the filepath is just the same where all the programs are in java\bin. the open and save features work, so why not this one?

Comment: did you add the extension of the file(.txt) to the end of fileName?